# How can I warm up a private ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: c#, web, console, console-application

In order to warm up a private website every 10 minutes, I created a console app to request an url with `HttpWebRequest`.

I don't know if this is best solution, if not please let me know :)

The issue with this way is the connection, I can't pass the login page, some people says to use CookieContainer but that do not replace sessions.

Please share your advice, thanks.

Comment: Actually, You are calling with the timer (every 10 mins will call one time), Aren't you?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. please add extra information

Answer (score 2):

There is a built in feature in IIS to preload applications. Of course it always depends on the environment you are using,  but if on windows with IIS there is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization

Basically, this can enable many features per application and hit specific URLs.

Configuration is as simple as adding some configs to your files like this

```
<applicationInitialization
        remapManagedRequestsTo="Startup.htm" 
        skipManagedModules="true" >
     <add initializationPage="/default.aspx" />
</applicationInitialization>
```

I suggest this way, as it's very easy and you can provides more options than a simple application, like the always on feature where IIS knows an application has been recycled and waits for warmup before letting it accept new requests.

> When IIS detects that an active worker process is being recycled, IIS does not switch active traffic over to the new recycled worker process until the new worker process finishes running all application initialization Urls in the new process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can it fake session ? because if i load search page for example, i need to have the user session defined otherwise it will return error 500

Comment: Why do you care about the error 500? Whatever the answer, the application has warmed up. Or do you mean ntlm authentication?

Comment: I need to initialize my sessions website, keep cache alive etc. that's why the best way is to access directly to the website